# JQuery client side resize with loading error / getting height width of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first post, so, please, be nice 
removing these lines.

```
<!--This 1x1 picture size workaround is a real flower-->
<img src="" id="preview" width="1" height="1">
```

causes the below script to malfunction. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imageFile').change(function(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        //reader.onprogess = function(event) {
        //      document.getElementById('progressbar').innerHTML = "Progressbar";
        //      sleep 
        //    };
        if (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
    
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('preview').src = e.target.result;
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Upload succesful";
    ResizeImage();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });
});

function ResizeImage() {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('imageFile').files;
        var file = filesToUpload[0];
        if (file) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Set the image once loaded into file reader
            reader.onload = function(e) {

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = e.target.result;

                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;
                
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
                document.getElementById('output').src = dataurl;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }

    } else {
        alert('Not working so well in this browser');
    }
}
  </script>
</head> 
<input id="imageFile" name="imageFile" type="file" class="imageFile"  accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"/> 
<br/>
<!--This 1x1 picture size workaround is a real flower-->
<img src="" id="preview" width="1" height="1">
<p id="status">status</p>
<img src="" id="output">
```

Comment: How did you determine that something is not working? Is there any error message involved?

Comment: Did not get any errors but the resize is not working, however if you run the snippet you have to remove that <img> line from the code snippet because i posted it with the workaround, that i want to remove.

Comment: What do you mean by "resize is not working"? What have you tried to debug the problem? Where is the execution stuck?

Comment: The execution is not stuck, when you delete document.getElementById('preview').src = e.target.result; and <img src="" id="preview" width="1" height="1"> the script does not work and I do not understand why. When i debug it you cant resolve the width and height of the image indication that something is incorrect in load of the image. Since only when the preloaded preview image is loaded it works.

Comment: Then, if the execution is running properly, what exactly does not work and what have you tried to debug the problem? There are excellent ways of debugging JS in every current browser

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adk1q5pj/

Comment: and the only thing i get is msg [Violation] 'load' handler took 4813ms when i put a breakpoint in resize script nothing else

Comment: If you debug your code, which parts are run, which are not?

Comment: i think that all parts runs, but there is a poor understanding of jquery limiting my though process since it seems like the image is not properly loaded before asking the properties of the img for example the height. or that by caching the image this is eliminated.

Comment: @NicoHaase if you look at the fiddle, you cant make it run, i tried to clearify that by making a separate example. The built in snippet on stackoverflow work with the workaround. What I want to understand of how you can remove it. Using the chrome browser to debug but can figure out why this is occuring.

Comment: @NicoHaase, the problem with the code is that it lacks callback to properly load the image at start time, due to the asynchronous behaviour causing this glitch.

Comment: So, if you have identified this as a problem, please edit your question accordingly such that it contains all relevant information and the updated question: **why** is the callback not triggered after loading the image?